# Slim Framework always return 404 Error

Tags: php, api, frameworks, slim

These days i'm using **Slim Framework** as my simplest tool to develop the php web api.
Using these two articles:

- [Coenraets](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/restful-services-with-jquery-php-and-the-slim-framework/)
- [CodingThis](http://codingthis.com/programming/php/using-the-slim-php-framework-for-developing-rest-apis/comment-page-1/#comment-24213)

I follow some of the steps from there. Downloading the Slim Framework, putting the correct directory & files. Adjusting the initation statements such as;

```
//1. Require Slim
require('Slim/Slim.php');

//2. Instantiate Slim
$app = new Slim();

//3. Define routes
$app->get('/books', function ($id) {
    //Show book with id = $id
});
```

And then, I modify the rest accordingly.

Such as my checklist that already done:

- LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so -> enabled
- Slim .htaccess:

> RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteRule
>   ^(.*)$ bootstrap.php [QSA,L]

- httpd.conf: [(Shared Link).](http://pastebin.ca/2128997)

But, after Once I run this statement;

```
$app->run();
```

And I run it on my browser.... then, I got **404 Error** while testing it on my Localhost. What's the solution for fixing that?

FYI, here is my simplest PHP file that i'm currently using it. [(shared Link)](http://www.text-upload.com/read.php?id=310286&c=9624149)

Comment: For people who come with this problem in the future ... let me help you with this issue!
This problem can be solved not just by writting the right url, but also by having the right implementation... please visit this site https://github.com/codeguy/Slim and follow the steps, and voilà! you´ll get it hope it helps, have a great one everyone!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Problem is solved!

My apache is actually normal, and the .htaccess file provided earlier also normal.

The clue is the URL that I used.
Previously I used the invalid URL, thus it returned the 404 page error.
I just realized it when I Tried to access the newer GET URL via browser with this one;

```
http://localhost/dev/index.php/getUsers/user1
```

and now that works!

I just realized it once I found these statements;

> If Slim does not find routes with URIs that match the HTTP request
>   URI, Slim will automatically return a 404 Not Found response.
>
> If Slim finds routes with URIs that match the HTTP request URI but not
>   the HTTP request method, Slim will automatically return a 405 Method
>   Not Allowed response with an Allow: header whose value lists HTTP
>   methods that are acceptable for the requested resource.

Comment: Just to clarify the problem, what was the URL that you were trying to use before ?

Answer (score 28):

I found this post while googling "slimframework 404". The post led me to a solution to my problem.

**The Problem**

I set up a site with the Slim framework using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) and create an index.php with the following example code form slimframework.com:

```
<?php
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {
    echo "Hello, $name";
});
$app->run();
```

Then I try to access the page using `http://localhost/hello/bob`. I get back a 404 Page Not Found page.

I was able to get to access the page using `http://localhost/index.php/hello/bob`.

**The Solution**

I found the solution by looking at `/vendor/slim/.htaccess` (included w/ Composer Slim install) and the [URL Rewriting](http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/rewrite/) section of the Slim framework documentation.

I added a copy of the `/vendor/slim/.htaccess` file to the same folder as my index.php file. The contents of the file are:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Now I can access the page using `http://localhost/hello/bob`.

Comment: If proble persist even after adding the correct `.htaccess` file then make sure your virtual host is configured with the `AllowOverride` option so that the .htaccess rewrite rules can be used:                                         `<Directory /var/www/html>
         AllowOverride All
         Order deny,allow
         Allow from All
     </Directory>`

Comment: Hi @cutRateGamer, i use AllowOverride All but server show me error 500.

Comment: Tod-birdsall answer + anj comment = the solution

Comment: Thanks, would have been digging forever to discover this solution.

Answer (score 5):

You're right about to include the index.php on your file, but that happen because you're not working properly with your mod-rewrite
Please check the following link:

https://github.com/codeguy/Slim

In the Get Started part you could see how to configure your server (in case that you were using apache / lighttpd / ngynx)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is at the "Resource parser" because you are no defining $id parameter at the request so, please, try this:

```
//1. Require Slim
require('Slim/Slim.php');

//2. Instantiate Slim
$app = new Slim();

//3. Define routes
$app->get('/books/:id/', function ($id) {
    echo json_encode( getBook($id) );
});

// some stuff
$app->run();
```

Please, tell us if it's ok

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that I'd forgotten to provide a `.htaccess` file in my document root.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Slim on Ubuntu 16.04 and you're getting the 404 error.  Try this test from Tod Birdsall above:

If this works

http://localhost/index.php/hello/bob

and this doesnt work

http://localhost/hello/bob

and your .htaccess file in the same directory as your index.php and is configured as follows:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
```

And you still get the 404 error on Apache.

Try turning on Apache mod_rewrite as follows and restart Apache:

$sudo a2enmod rewrite

$sudo service apache2 restart

The Slim API should work correctly now as the provided .htaccess file will only work if mod_rewrite is enabled and that not the default on a clean install.

Here is how to turn off mod_rewirte if you need to.

$sudo a2dismod rewrite

$sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

Additionally `mod_rewrite.so` module must be loaded in `httpd.conf` or you will receive error 500.

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Answer (score 0):

For people who still search answers because previous doesn't work, this works for me :

```
RewriteBase /<base_of_your_project>/
```