# PHP Composer throwing 404 URL not found

Tags: php, composer-php, slim

I'm starting to learn PHP and I'm trying to create an endpoint.

I installed Apache 2 and I'm placing my files under: `/var/www/html/`, however when I try to access it through `localhost/hello/foo` I'm getting a 404 error page:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /hello/foo was not found on this server.
```

This is my `composer.json`

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "^3.0"
    }
}
```

And my `index.php`:

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
  $name = $args['name'];
  $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");

  return $response;
});
$app->run();
```

As well as my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I have also tried adding those files along with some others into a folder inside `/var/www/html/sample` and trying to access it as `localhost/sample/hello/foo` but I'm having the same result.

Could someone provide any advice? As I said, I'm new to PHP and probably I'm missing something, but I don't know what it is.

### Edit

In the linked question as a possible dup, they say they can access their endpoints through: `localhost/index.php/hello/foo` however in my case, the problem stands even with that path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slim Framework always return 404 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747640/slim-framework-always-return-404-error)

Comment: @Frakcool. You may want to check the Apache configuration first. Just create a new folder (let's say projectFolder) with a simple index.html. See if you can call localhost/projectFolder  and get a response. If it is, then we can debug further.

Comment: @SantoshAchari thanks for your tip, I can get a response when I created a sample HTML file inside `/var/www/html/sample/index.html" and when I access `localhost/sample` I get a response back from it.

Comment: @user10089632 please see my edit

Comment: If you don't want to run the PHP web server, the answer is likely this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747640/slim-framework-always-return-404-error#comment50175185_30633620

Comment: I'm gonna try it just for the learning experience as well @drew010 thanks for your comment :)

Comment: You're welcome.  Basically, the default `AllowOverride None` means that the server is ignoring the .htaccess file that has the rewrite rules which is why the routed URLs don't work and you can only pull up files/scripts that actually exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to add the files to `/var/www/html/sample`, I went to my project path:

```
cd /path/to/project
```

And then I ran:

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

Now, I can access my endpoint as:

```
localhost:8000/hello/foo
```

And that's it!